# How to Perform Unit Testing for Embedded C (Methodology, rules)?

Tags: c, unit-testing

First of all, our definite goal is to find bugs and improve software quality. So the test is not limited to `unit test`.

I used to do software tests at an American aerospace incorporation. One kind of the tests is unit test. Some of its rules are:

- **All tests shall follow the requirement document and designment document, not the code.**
- SUT (software under test) is restricted to basic units, e.g., one or several functions/procedures. Of course, SUT may call other functions/procedures, but the latter are not focused at this test – they have their own tests, so they can be stubbed out.
- Call the SUT only. The test does not require the whole system to be setup.
- Verify and validate the results of the SUT as required by the requirement/designment document. E.g., some data is computed, some procedures are called…

Now I'm a programmer at a different incorporation. We have no requirement/designment document. The software is only tested via functional tests (black box) by the test department. Programmers here never do unit tests before. The task to perform unit testing is assigned to me. Here’s what I did:

1. Analysis the code and try to understand it;
2. Write a brief document for the unit (function) to be tested;
3. Test the SUT as mentioned above;

So for a function that sends a message to another process. I described it as:

- Allocate some memory for the message
- Populate the message header;
- Call the underlying facility to deliver the message.

What I verified and validated are (as the brief desc I wrote):

- It called some memory allocation API, such as malloc(), and allocated the desired amount of memory;
- The message header was populated correctly before being sent;
- It called the exact underlying API to deliver the message.

In my opinion, if software do exactly as per the designment document, the test should pass. **If it turned out to behave incorrectly, the DESIGNMENT shall be blamed, not the test method itself.**

**Unit test ensures that each `unit` of the software behaves correctly. Whether the units act correctly together, is the job of some higher level tests, such as integration test or system test.**

However some people argued that I must **start another process, create a receiver, to receive this message, and check its content.** Only this can I make sure that the procedure which sends the message behaves correctly.

I think this is out of the scope of `UNIT testing`. It can be called `integration testing`?

I’m not good at arguing. I cannot convince them. And I don't want to argue.

Could anyone help **figure out the correct method/principle to perform unit testing** – or any other kinds of tests, as I said at the beginning, our definite goal is to improve software quality.